# Set UTC date in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this snippet:

```
var _datePicker = $(this); // This is inside a cycle
_datePicker.datepicker("setDate", new Date(_datePicker.data("defaultdate")));
```

And it works ok, but the problem is data("defaultdate") is in UTC format, but when the calendar shows the date, it showed it using the timezone of the PC, so the date is wrong.

I've read the code of the datepicker ui code from jQuery, and I cannot find anyplace to fix that. Is there a way to do it?

**ADDING DEBUG INFORMATION**

```
console.log((new Date(_datePicker.data("defaultdate"))).getUTCDate(), _datePicker.attr("id"));
console.log(new Date(_datePicker.data("defaultdate")), _datePicker.attr("id"));
```

For this date: 1380844800000

The first one show 4 (which is correct), but in Mexico TZ the second one shows:

```
Date {Thu Oct 03 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)} start_picker
```

Comment: What does logging `new Date(_datePicker.data("defaultdate"))` show?

Comment: @raina77ow see update :) Tanks